# "TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required" When running a discord bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, python-asyncio

I am starting the creation of a discord bot and i don't know much.
I'm Following the steps here : https://www.docstring.fr/blog/creer-un-bot-discord-avec-python/#creation-du-bot

When i tried to launch the test to see if the bots logs well, i have this error :

```
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
```

My bot seems connected but i don't have the "Le bot est prêt" message (The bot is ready in french).

Here is my code :

```
import discord
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()
client = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.default())
client.run("MTE5Mzg1NTQ3MDg4MDk0ODIzNA.GPaUZJ.VOZB3ZzjPP6H_dsBy3dJNMWCrMAjV551JMWUmI")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Le bot est prêt !")
```

But when i launch it i have this gigantic error message :

```
[2024-01-08 12:22:56] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
[2024-01-08 12:22:56] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token

[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 164, in poll_one
    asyncio.run(handler(out_stream, ident, msg))
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 33, in run
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(main)
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 677, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 164, in poll_one
    asyncio.run(handler(out_stream, ident, msg))
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 33, in run
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(main)
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 677, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 164, in poll_one
    asyncio.run(handler(out_stream, ident, msg))
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 33, in run
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(main)
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 677, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 164, in poll_one
    asyncio.run(handler(out_stream, ident, msg))
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 33, in run
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(main)
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 677, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
[2024-01-08 12:22:57] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: f5f6a2ec06799ce78da0804b89bd514e).
[2024-01-08 12:22:57] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: f5f6a2ec06799ce78da0804b89bd514e).

[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 164, in poll_one
    asyncio.run(handler(out_stream, ident, msg))
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 33, in run
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(main)
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 677, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 164, in poll_one
    asyncio.run(handler(out_stream, ident, msg))
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 33, in run
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(main)
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 677, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 164, in poll_one
    asyncio.run(handler(out_stream, ident, msg))
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 33, in run
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(main)
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 677, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 164, in poll_one
    asyncio.run(handler(out_stream, ident, msg))
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 33, in run
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(main)
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 677, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 164, in poll_one
    asyncio.run(handler(out_stream, ident, msg))
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 33, in run
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(main)
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 677, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
[SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\comms\frontendcomm.py", line 164, in poll_one
    asyncio.run(handler(out_stream, ident, msg))
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 33, in run
    task = asyncio.ensure_future(main)
  File "C:\Users\pacha\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 677, in ensure_future
    raise TypeError('An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is '
TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required
```

What should I do ? I don't find any answer online.

Comment: I added that after to do more tries and the bot doesn't answer, with a similar error :
```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "Ping":
        await message.channel.send("Pong")
```

Comment: Please revoke the Discord bot token you've just published to the world.

Comment: Lmoa thanks a lot I forgot that detail when i checked what details i should erase befoer pasting this.
That's done